# Preventing URL Encoded XSS Attacks in PHP

Tags: php, url, xss

I am having a problem getting my website to become PCI compliant due to my site's vulnerablility to a XSS attack. I've tried using htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities(), however Trustwave is still saying that my site is vulnerable to URL encoded attacks. For instance, someone might input something like "%2522%253E%2527%253E%253CIfRaME%253E" in the url variable that I'm calling for and I'm not sure how to handle that. Please help!! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you really still trust Trustwave?

Comment: I might need a code example to understand your problem. Superglobals like $_GET are already decoded. So on your output you just need to use **htmlspecialchars** to protect your site against XSS attacks.

Answer (score 0):

My 2cent:

If you're using MVC, then try to decode all ofthe values before routing, and use `stript_tags()` to get rid of these nasties. And as the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) say, case should not impact anything.

If not, create a utility function and do the same while retrieveing the variables from the URI. But I am by no means an XSS expert, so this might be just a part of the trick.